# Button Click Listener Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button inside my activity layout,my Activity have extends and implement as MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks.
on Click Listener of button I am calling another activity using startActivity but it not going on other activity even logs and try catch not getting any exception.
Anyone can suggest me what can be the possible things I need to check to get away this issue ?
Great thanks in advance. . .

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.categories);
            Context context;
            context = this;
        imgViewLogin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewLogin);
        imgViewLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                startActivity(new Intent(context,
                         NewActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you put your code ?

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
```

here MainActivity means your current activity where you place this code.
instead of

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, NewActivity.class));
```

Comment: Hi I did copy past code in word ,I am using context as Context context;context = this;context not as null,I debug code context have current activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use **getApplicationContext() or activity.this**

**getApplicationContext()** -

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.categories);
    imgViewLogin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewLogin);
    imgViewLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                     NewActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

**acivity.this** -

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.categories);
        imgViewLogin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewLogin);
        imgViewLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                startActivity(new Intent(activity.this,
                         NewActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi I did copy past code in word and forget two lines ,I am using context as Context context;context = this;context not as null,I debug code context have current activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                         NewActivity.class));
```